# How to push/build a docker image in release process via sbt-release

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-release, sbt-docker

I used [sbt-release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) to control release process and [sbt-docker](https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/sbt-docker) to build/publish a docker image.

I can release a specific version via `sbt release` and build/publish a docker image via `sbt docker` or `sbt dockerBuildAndPush'

If I wanna release a specific version, I need to

1. execute `sbt release`
2. remember the release version and modify docker image tag with the release version
3. execute `sbt dockerBuildAndPush`

But it's so tedious...

I wanna add build/publish docker image into release process.

For example:

I define my release process in `build.sbt`

```
val publishDocker = ReleaseStep(action = st => {
  // 1. get release version from sbt-release
  // 2. add release version to docker image tag
  // 3. push docker image to aws ecr
})

releaseProcess := Seq[ReleaseStep](
  checkSnapshotDependencies,            
  inquireVersions,                      
  runTest,                                
  setReleaseVersion,                     
  commitReleaseVersion,                   
  tagRelease,                            
  publishDocker,                      
  setNextVersion,                        
  commitNextVersion,                      
  pushChanges                            
)
```

But I have no idea how to implement publishDocker function.

Answer (score 1):

@ed Thanks for your advice and I solved it by myself :>

This is my sbt: https://gist.github.com/pandaforme/e378dc3f1f32aa252b14e40937491e9c

I just execute `sbt release` and it'll automatically compile, generate release version, build and push docker image, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to publish Docker image in release process would be:

```
releaseProcess := {
  import ReleaseTransformations._
  Seq[ReleaseStep](
    // ... prev steps
    ReleaseStep(releaseStepTask(Docker / publish)),
    // ... next steps
  )
}
```

[Credits](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/475#issuecomment-286439257)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not familiar with `sbt-docker` but you can get the `version` from the `st: State` parameter:

```scala
val publishDocker = ReleaseStep(action = st => {
  // 1. get version from sbt
  // (it was set by sbt-release in setReleaseVersion)
  val extracted = Project.extract(st)
  val version:String = extracted.get(sbt.Keys.version)

})
```