# Add docker publish step to sbt-release process with new tag

Tags: scala, docker, continuous-integration, sbt, sbt-release

I'm integrating the sbt-release plugin to our projects, in order to delegate all the build+publish tasks to it.

It basically does all we need, but I'm adding an additional ReleaseStep to it: publishing a Docker image. This is my current releaseProcess (as per [this](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release#can-we-finally-customize-that-release-process-please)):

```
releaseProcess := Seq[ReleaseStep](
  checkSnapshotDependencies,
  inquireVersions,
  runTest,
  setReleaseVersion,
  commitReleaseVersion,
  tagRelease,
  //publishArtifacts,
  releaseStepCommand("docker"),
  setNextVersion,
  commitNextVersion
  //pushChanges,
)
```

(commented push-related stuff not to break anything upstream)

It's mostly fine and dandy, except the tag that the resulting Docker image gets.

For example, if the project was version 0.17.0-SNAPSHOT, and I wanted to release version 1.0.0, something like this would happen:

```
[develop] ✓ [17:54:22] lithium : ~/devel/some-company/some-app
➤ sbt clean "release skip-tests"
[info] Loading project definition from /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/project
[info] Updating {file:/opt/devel/some-company/some-app/project/}some-app-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to someapp (in build file:/opt/devel/some-company/some-app/)
[warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'local'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate project resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publishing resolver (`publishTo`).
[warn] Credentials file /var/jenkins_home/credentials/nexus_creds does not exist
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed May 18, 2017 5:54:56 PM
[info] Starting release process off commit: a7acde4d0e943be1e4befa6cc70dc873e164044a
[warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'local'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate project resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publishing resolver (`publishTo`).
[warn] Credentials file /var/jenkins_home/credentials/nexus_creds does not exist
[info] Updating {file:/opt/devel/some-company/some-app/}root...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] Found intransitive dependency (net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:4.7) while publishMavenStyle is true, but Maven repositories
[warn]   do not support intransitive dependencies. Use exclusions instead so transitive dependencies
[warn]   will be correctly excluded in dependent projects.
[warn]            
Release version [0.17.0] : 1.0.0
Next version [1.0.1-SNAPSHOT] : 
[info] Setting version to '1.0.0'.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to someapp (in build file:/opt/devel/some-company/some-app/)
[info] [develop db69b0a] Setting version to 1.0.0
[info]  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to someapp (in build file:/opt/devel/some-company/some-app/)
[info] Packaging /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/target/scala-2.11/someapp_2.11-0.17.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar ...
[warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'local'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate project resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publishing resolver (`publishTo`).
[warn] Credentials file /var/jenkins_home/credentials/nexus_creds does not exist
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Wrote /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/target/scala-2.11/someapp_2.11-0.17.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
Warning: node.js detection failed, sbt will use the Rhino based Trireme JavaScript engine instead to run JavaScript assets compilation, which in some cases may be orders of magnitude slower than using node.js.
[info] Packaging /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/target/scala-2.11/someapp_2.11-0.17.0-SNAPSHOT-web-assets.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Compiling 107 Scala sources and 36 Java sources to /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/target/scala-2.11/api...
[warn] Class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue not found - continuing with a stub.
[warn] /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/app/services/DOPXHandlerActor.scala:44: non-variable type argument services.DOPX in type pattern List[services.DOPX] (the underlying of List[services.DOPX]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
[warn]     case reqs:List[DOPX] => withMDC { // PASAR A CASE CLASS 
[warn]               ^
[warn] /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/app/services/DOPXHandlerActor.scala:44: non-variable type argument services.DOPX in type pattern List[services.DOPX] (the underlying of List[services.DOPX]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
[warn]     case reqs:List[DOPX] => withMDC { // PASAR A CASE CLASS 
[warn]               ^
[warn] /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/app/controllers/TransactionController.scala:79: match may not be exhaustive.
[warn] It would fail on the following input: (None, Success(_))
[warn]               paymentConfirmationsService.confirm(siteId, chargeId, operationResource, request.headers.get("user")) map { _ match  {
[warn]                                                                                                                           ^
[warn] there were 15 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
[warn] /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/app/services/DistributedTransactionProcessor.scala:139: match may not be exhaustive.
[warn] It would fail on the following input: Some(_)
[warn]     failureResponse match {
[warn]     ^
[warn] /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/app/services/DistributedTransactionProcessor.scala:312: match may not be exhaustive.
[warn] It would fail on the following inputs: (_, Failure(_)), (_, Success(_))
[warn]       distributedOperationProcessor.processDistributedOPx(opDataFatherFixed.chargeId, Rechazada(), opDataFatherFixed, None, meanPayment, Some(refundSubPaymentOperations)).map( pr => pr match {
[warn]                                                                                                                                                                                       ^
model contains 337 documentable templates
[warn] /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/app/services/refunds/RefundService.scala:346: match may not be exhaustive.
[warn] It would fail on the following input: None
[warn]                 operation.sub_transactions.find { subTx => subTx.subpayment_id.get == subpaymentId } match {
[warn]                                                 ^
[warn] /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/app/services/ApplicationTimer.scala:9: Could not find any member to link for "ApplicationLifecycle".
[warn] /**
[warn] ^
[warn] three warnings found
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/target/scala-2.11/someapp_2.11-0.17.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[warn] there were 15 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
[warn] 30 warnings found
[warn] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
[info] /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/app/legacy/some-company/sps/domain/DBParametros.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[info] /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/app/legacy/some-company/sps/domain/DBParametros.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[info] Packaging /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/target/scala-2.11/someapp_2.11-0.17.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /opt/devel/some-company/some-app/target/scala-2.11/someapp_2.11-0.17.0-SNAPSHOT-sans-externalized.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Sending build context to Docker daemon  108.9MB
[info] Step 1/8 : FROM lapp-dvde004:5000/java-alpine:latest
[info]  ---> fd94b5262b7b
[info] Step 2/8 : MAINTAINER Redbee
[info]  ---> Using cache
[info]  ---> 2905e1a8a792
[info] Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /opt/docker
[info]  ---> Using cache
[info]  ---> 0b2f169737f6
[info] Step 4/8 : ADD opt/ /opt
[info]  ---> a973fb66a793
[info] Removing intermediate container f6da68f8a1c3
[info] Step 5/8 : ADD opt/docker/conf/jce_policy-8.tar.gz /usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm/jre/lib/security/
[info]  ---> 3fda5972ddd5
[info] Removing intermediate container cb10f1fcf2dd
[info] Step 6/8 : RUN chown -R daemon:daemon .
[info]  ---> Running in 867093c046e0
[info]  ---> 60a969ff427c
[info] Removing intermediate container 867093c046e0
[info] Step 7/8 : USER daemon
[info]  ---> Running in a7fa422e326c
[info]  ---> 8857a5a5392b
[info] Removing intermediate container a7fa422e326c
[info] Step 8/8 : ENTRYPOINT /opt/docker/conf/wrapper.sh
[info]  ---> Running in 31887383f984
[info]  ---> 2418dba2d69e
[info] Removing intermediate container 31887383f984
[info] Successfully built 2418dba2d69e
[info] Successfully tagged lapp-dvde004:5000/someapp:0.17.0-SNAPSHOT
[info] Built image lapp-dvde004:5000/someapp:0.17.0-SNAPSHOT
[info] Update Latest from image lapp-dvde004:5000/someapp:0.17.0-SNAPSHOT
[success] Total time: 58 s, completed May 18, 2017 5:56:07 PM
[info] Setting version to '1.0.1-SNAPSHOT'.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to someapp (in build file:/opt/devel/some-company/some-app/)
[info] [develop a1dd63d] Setting version to 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info]  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Sadly I cannot highlight code, but it says:

```
[info] Setting version to '1.0.0'.
[info] Reapplying settings...
```

And then the built image is:

```
[info] Built image lapp-dvde004:5000/someapp:0.17.0-SNAPSHOT
```

In my limited understanding, it seems like sbt-release and sbt-docker (or sbt-native-packager, I tried with both) do not share the same build context? Something along those lines?

sbt-release successfully changes the version.sbt file before sbt-docker kicks in, but still the latter pays no mind to it.

Any ideas?

PS: Funfact: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418201/how-to-push-build-a-docker-image-in-release-process-via-sbt-release) apparently had the answer (or at least his requirements matched mine), so, pandaforme, if you read this, why did you delete that gist!? :(

Comment: I cannot speak for [pandaforme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1834805/pandaforme) but I've found a newer gist (created on May 19, 2017) that solves the problem of publishing Docker images. https://gist.github.com/pandaforme/e378dc3f1f32aa252b14e40937491e9c

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the amazing pandaforme who re-uploaded the aforementioned gist, it's now working.

So, I implemented two things: A 'release' process which also builds a Docker image, and also a custom task 'publishSnapshot' which is sort of an extension to 'publish' (publishes the snapshot and it's docker image; also known as "overengineering when I could just do `sbt publish dockerBuildAndPush`").

Implementation, if anyone needs it:

```
val publishDocker = ReleaseStep(action = st => {
  val extr: Extracted = Project.extract(st)
  val ref: ProjectRef = extr.get(thisProjectRef)
  extr.runAggregated(
    sbtdocker.DockerKeys.dockerBuildAndPush in sbtdocker.DockerPlugin.autoImport.docker in ref,
    st
  )
  st
})

lazy val publishSnapshot = taskKey[Unit]("Publish a Snapshot and it's Docker image")
publishSnapshot in Compile := Def.sequential(
  publish in Compile,
  sbtdocker.DockerKeys.dockerBuildAndPush in sbtdocker.DockerPlugin.autoImport.docker
).value

releaseProcess := Seq[ReleaseStep](
  checkSnapshotDependencies,
  inquireVersions,
  runTest,
  setReleaseVersion,
  commitReleaseVersion,
  tagRelease,
  publishArtifacts,
  publishDocker,
  setNextVersion,
  commitNextVersion,
  pushChanges
)
```

Comment: `sbtdocker` does not appear to be defined for me.

Comment: publishDocker can be one-lined with `ReleaseStep(releaseStepTask(sbtdocker.DockerKeys.dockerBuildAndPush))`